# SoundLink Mini I's Support for aac

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

I'm using Soundlink Mini I with my macbook pro, running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I'm unable to get Soundlink Mini from using aac. 
This is what I have done:

```
Download and open "Bluetooth Explorer"
Open "audio option" window
Select "enable aac"
Turn Soundlink Mini on. It won't connect (disconnect/reconnect repeatedly).
Unselect "enable aac"
Turn Soundlink Mini on. It connect immediately.
```

This is the log I get:

```
Process: Bluetooth Explorer 6.0.9
Operating System: Version 10.13.6 (Build 17G65)
Date: 2020-02-16 05:17:32 +0000

Initializing Bluetooth...
Bluetooth Support Initialization complete.
updateChainPower error: 82
Audio Graph: Initializing...
Audio Graph: Bluetooth Support Initialization complete.
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
2020-02-16 05:17:44 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x16
2020-02-16 05:17:44 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x16
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Feb 16 13:17:43 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.security.cloudkeychainproxy3[80827]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Feb 16 13:17:43 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.security.cloudkeychainproxy3): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Feb 16 13:17:44 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bluetoothaudiod): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.

2020-02-16 05:17:46 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:17:53 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:17:53 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:17:53 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:17:53 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:17:53 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
2020-02-16 05:17:59 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:17:59 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:17:59 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:17:59 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x08
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:17:59 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
2020-02-16 05:18:05 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:18:05 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:18:05 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:18:05 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:18:06 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
2020-02-16 05:18:12 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:18:12 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:18:12 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:18:12 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x08
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:18:13 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
Feb 16 13:18:11 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.mathpix.com-mathpix-snipping-tool-noappstore-helper[80863]): Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 155: Refusing to execute/trust quarantined program/file: com.mathpix.com-mathpix-snipping-tool-noappstore-helper
Feb 16 13:18:11 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.mathpix.com-mathpix-snipping-tool-noappstore-helper): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Feb 16 13:18:13 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bluetoothaudiod): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.

2020-02-16 05:18:19 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:18:19 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:18:19 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:18:19 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:18:20 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:18:26 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:18:26 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:18:26 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:18:26 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:18:26 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
2020-02-16 05:18:51 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:18:51 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:18:51 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:18:51 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
Feb 16 13:18:49 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.qiuyuzhou.shadowsocksX-NG.http[80903]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Feb 16 13:18:49 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.qiuyuzhou.shadowsocksX-NG.http): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Feb 16 13:18:51 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bluetoothaudiod): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.

2020-02-16 05:18:56 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
2020-02-16 05:19:09 +0000 Mode change 12 for handle: 0x2
2020-02-16 05:19:09 +0000 Mode change 12 for handle: 0x2
2020-02-16 05:19:10 +0000 Mode change 12 for handle: 0x0
2020-02-16 05:19:10 +0000 Mode change 12 for handle: 0x0
2020-02-16 05:19:10 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x16
2020-02-16 05:19:10 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x16
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:19:11 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
2020-02-16 05:19:43 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x2
2020-02-16 05:19:43 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x2
2020-02-16 05:19:58 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x0
2020-02-16 05:19:58 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x0
2020-02-16 05:20:00 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x16
2020-02-16 05:20:00 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x16
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:20:01 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
2020-02-16 05:20:14 +0000 Mode change 12 for handle: 0x2
2020-02-16 05:20:14 +0000 Mode change 12 for handle: 0x2
2020-02-16 05:20:17 +0000 Mode change 12 for handle: 0x0
2020-02-16 05:20:17 +0000 Mode change 12 for handle: 0x0
2020-02-16 05:20:49 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x16
2020-02-16 05:20:49 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x16
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:20:50 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
2020-02-16 05:20:57 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:20:57 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:20:57 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:20:57 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:20:57 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:20:57 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:20:57 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
2020-02-16 05:21:03 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:21:03 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:21:03 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:21:03 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x08
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:21:03 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:21:03 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:21:06 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
2020-02-16 05:21:12 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:21:12 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:21:12 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:21:12 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:21:12 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:21:12 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:21:13 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
Feb 16 13:21:12 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bluetoothaudiod): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
Feb 16 13:21:13 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.mathpix.com-mathpix-snipping-tool-noappstore-helper[81044]): Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 155: Refusing to execute/trust quarantined program/file: com.mathpix.com-mathpix-snipping-tool-noappstore-helper
Feb 16 13:21:13 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.mathpix.com-mathpix-snipping-tool-noappstore-helper): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.

2020-02-16 05:21:18 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:21:18 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:21:19 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:21:19 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x08
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:21:20 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
2020-02-16 05:21:33 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x16
2020-02-16 05:21:33 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x16
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:21:34 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
2020-02-16 05:21:38 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x16
2020-02-16 05:21:38 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x16
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Feb 16 13:21:39 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.qiuyuzhou.shadowsocksX-NG.http[81087]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Feb 16 13:21:39 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.qiuyuzhou.shadowsocksX-NG.http): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Feb 16 13:21:40 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bluetoothaudiod): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
Feb 16 13:21:41 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[81102]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook

Feb 16 13:21:41 Joys-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bluetoothaudiod): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.

2020-02-16 05:21:43 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
2020-02-16 05:21:54 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x16
2020-02-16 05:21:54 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x16
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:21:55 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
2020-02-16 05:22:01 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:22:01 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:22:01 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:22:01 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x08
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:22:01 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:22:01 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:22:01 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
2020-02-16 05:22:07 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:22:07 +0000 Handle: 0x0 disconnected, reason: 0x00
2020-02-16 05:22:07 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
2020-02-16 05:22:07 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xC
2020-02-16 05:22:09 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
2020-02-16 05:22:19 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x16
2020-02-16 05:22:19 +0000 Handle: 0xC disconnected, reason: 0x16
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
Bose Mini SoundLink disconnected
2020-02-16 05:22:20 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0xC00
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
Bose Mini SoundLink connected, handle: 0xB
2020-02-16 06:22:16 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x2
2020-02-16 06:22:16 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x2
```

When I run Bluetooth, it showed that this device supports aac.
[image]
It also throws two errors.[image]